# Firestore query works twice in Geoquery

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Geoquery to fetch nearest documents from Firestore in Android. But somehow, `startAfter(lastVisible)` clause makes the query work twice for different bound tasks. So, after first fetch, all queries works twice.

My first query is:

```
        List<GeoQueryBounds> bounds = GeoFireUtils.getGeoHashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
        final List<Task<QuerySnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GeoQueryBounds b : bounds) {
            Query firstQuery = db.collection("posts")
                    .whereEqualTo("country_code", sharedpreferences.getString("country_code", ""))
                    .orderBy("geohash")
                    .startAt(b.startHash)
                    .endAt(b.endHash)
                    .limit(10);

            tasks.add(firstQuery.get());
        }
```

My next query is:

```
        List<GeoQueryBounds> bounds = GeoFireUtils.getGeoHashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
        final List<Task<QuerySnapshot>> nextTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GeoQueryBounds b : bounds) {
            Query nextQuery = db.collection("posts")
                    .whereEqualTo("country_code", sharedpreferences.getString("country_code", ""))
                    .orderBy("geohash")
                    .startAt(b.startHash)
                    .endAt(b.endHash)
                    .startAfter(lastVisible)
                    .limit(10);

            nextTasks.add(nextQuery.get());
        }
```

Comment: Does your `nextTasks` list contain two items?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Actually it contains items as the count of the bounds. Bounds could be up to 9 based on GeoFire.  This shouldn't be a problem. Cause first query contains 2 tasks too but  works as intended without  `startAfter(lastVisible)`.